# Return to main view controller when app goes in background

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In my app I have tree view controllers, when the app enters background I want the app to get back to the main view controller. My app is a single application without `UINavigationController`.

I know that I have to implement this inside:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

}
```

but I am not sure how to tell the app to return to the main view controller.

How can I do this?

UPDATE

I have made a small [example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9zuA_b7fzjJQTJ4d0w3Z3l4TTQ) that takes the app to the main view controllers when enters background. 
The first Time it goes background the app works fine after I start to get a warning. How can I resolve the warning?

Comment: It depends....  What code do you use to navigate to these other controllers?

Comment: I am using `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromMainViewToFirstView", sender: self)`

Comment: I have also tried to use ` NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            "SegueFromFirstToMainView", object: nil)` it works however, I get a warning `Attempt to present <TEST.MainViewController: 0x1591dcc00> on <TEST.FirstViewController: 0x15880dc00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: Try having your non-main controller listen for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` messages and dismiss itself if it receives one.

Comment: where should I put this ?

Comment: Here a small example that shows the warning `https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9zuA_b7fzjJQTJ4d0w3Z3l4TTQ`. The first time I go background is fine after I start to get the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your fixed [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sdgSroa2ofTWZvblY2cjFUNnc/view?usp=sharing). The catch was to just to set the `rootViewcontroller` of `Appdelegate's window` like this when the application goes to background

```
 let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let mainViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainView") as! ViewController
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
 appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
```

Comment: if you want to save the last vc from where the app navigated to main vc... just push the viewcontroller

Comment: @Garry yes that is correct but he want to go to main menu when coming from background